# Sum of Variance

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, card-games

I came across the following question.

What is the variance of 26 cards (assuming cards values are between 1 and 13)?

The answer for the question involved finding the variance for 1 card and multiplying this by 26. I am well aware that Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) when X, Y independent. However, how come we sum the variance here given that we are not finding the variance of the sum of the 26 cards, but simply the variance of the 26 cards?

Comment: "What is the variance of 26 cards (regular values 1-13)?" does not make sense

Comment: If we draw 26 cards, what is the variance amongst those cards?

Comment: How do you define the quantity "the variance amongst the 26 cards"?

Comment: Do you mean the variance in the values of 26 cards drawn from a regular 52-card deck?

Comment: Essentially, what is your random variable that you are trying to calculate the variance of?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Var(X) where X represents 26 cards drawn from a regular deck.

Comment: Variance is generally defined in the context of real valued random variables. “X represents 26 cards drawn from a regular deck” has no meaning in this context, without further specification

Comment: Could you please show me then how to calculate variance Var(X) for the following 2 cases: 1)X: Sum of 26 cards with replacement 2)X: Average of 26 cards drawn with replacement